# Ubuntu Command 'pip' not found, but there are 18 similar ones

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, path, pip

I am trying to install a toolkit, I'm on WSL using ubuntu - I downloaded ubuntu yesterday. Here is what the installation process looks like for this toolkit.  *On windows cmd it says I have python 3.7.9 but on ubuntu its saying I have python 3.8.2*

```
git clone https://github.com...
cd program
pip install -e .
```

or:

```
pip install program
```

`pip install -e .` is not working for me, I get this error:

```
user@DESKTOP-REA10BN:~/gym$ pip install -e .

Command 'pip' not found, but there are 18 similar ones.
```

however, I checked and I have pip installed, here's what I checked for before running:

```
user@DESKTOP-REA10BN:~$ cd\
> sudo apt-get install python-pip
cdsudo: command not found
user@DESKTOP-REA10BN:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
user@DESKTOP-REA10BN:~$ python3-pip --version
python3-pip: command not found
user@DESKTOP-REA10BN:~$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
user@DESKTOP-REA10BN:~$ pip3 -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

**my PATHS:**

```
/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2020.812.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/windows/system32:/mnt/c/windows:/mnt/c/windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/:/mnt/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Now what made you think that `pip` and `pip3` are the same thing?

Comment: Never use `pip` or `pip3` directly. Always use `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip` instead. -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: as a noob, why is using pip or pip3 bad, I already installed pip3 and now my problem is fixed, should I uninstall and do it your way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Short answer: Try running `python3 -m pip install -e .`

---

Some explanations:

The different versions of Python are not surprising. WSL is, effectively, an ultra-lightweight virtual machine. Your Windows python installation is entirely independent of the WSL python installation.

Python has two widely used major versions, Python 2 and Python 3. The command `python` runs some minor version of Python 2, while the command `python3` runs some minor version of Python 3. Below is my console output.

```
lawruble@Balrog:~/scratch$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
lawruble@Balrog:~/scratch$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

Pip is the python installation manager, and has the same major versions as Python. The command `pip` runs the Python 2 version of pip, while `pip3` runs the Python 3 version of pip.

It's better practice to use `python3 -m pip` over `pip3`, it helps ensure that you're using the version of pip associated with the version of python you expect to run.

Answer (score 26):

### Trying doing these first/again

1. Updating package info

```
sudo apt-get update
```

2. Downloading all upgrades

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

3. Reinstalling pip

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Clearly the issue's with terminal, i.e. not recognizing the command so maybe pip isn't installed properly, but with what you've shown so far I don't think this issue should arise. Anyways give it a try.

#### Also

What are you trying to install?
pip is for python packages right.

Comment: yes. I think ubuntu 20 is still problematic, so I am trying ubuntu 18 right now

Comment: Just use : pip3 install <package name>