# How to install numpy on linux subsystem for windows?

Tags: windows, numpy, ubuntu

I'm trying to install NumPy on the Linux subsystem for Windows, but it when I try to install pip `sudo apt install python-pip` so that I can use `pip install numpy`, it gives the error `E: Unable to locate package python-pip`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Edit:
When I run `pip install numpy` it gives the error: `Command 'pip' not found, but there are 18 similar ones.`
My recollection is also that python did not come installed with ubuntu, but I could be remembering incorrectly.

Comment: the python that is bundled with ubuntu should already have pip

Comment: @PaulH When I run `pip install numpy` it gives the error: `Command 'pip' not found, but there are 18 similar ones.`  I also think that I needed to install python myself, but I don't entirely remember.

Comment: you should check if you have python installed

Comment: @PaulH I definitely have python, I think that it didn't come with the install.

Comment: try `pip3`.  It probably means that WSL comes with python3 and not python2.

Comment: @Nachiket I need to use python 2, otherwise `raw_input()` doesn't work, I tried installing pip3 and then pip, but only pip3 installed, I still got the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64163528/861716

Answer (score 0):

Try this `sudo apt install python3-pip`